# How to query ODBC with Dapper with multiple parameters including a WHERE IN?

Tags: sql, odbc, dapper

I've hit an issue using Dapper to query an ODBC provider. The query in question is supplied several parameters. One of the parameters is used to populate a WHERE IN operator.

So far I've tried supplying the query with: `DynamicParameters`, `?` regular parameters, `?name?` pseudo-positional parameters and some combinations of these.

```sql
SELECT companyId
    ,projectId
    ,contractId
    ,status
FROM certificate
WHERE companyId = ?companyId?
    AND projectId = ?projectId?
    AND contractId = ?contractId?
    AND invoiceId IN ?invoiceIds?
```

```cs
var results = await connection
    .QueryAsync<Certificate>(query, new { companyId, projectId, contractId, invoiceIds = new string[] { '1a', '1b', '2a' }});
```

Expected results are several rows being returned. If I hardcode the query with it's parameters it works fine, so the data I'm supplying should return rows.

Instead I'm getting an exception with the following message:

```
ERROR [07001] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Value has not been specified for parameter 4.
ERROR [07001] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Value has not been specified for parameter 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your code, then your code doesn't compile. You are not supplying any values for the first three parameters and you are giving illegal characters instead of string in the fourth parameter. I see no reason why this shouldn't work:

```
var results = await connection
    .QueryAsync<Certificate>(query, 
         new { companyId=1, projectId=1, contractId=1, invoiceIds = new [] { "1a", "1b", "2a" }});
```